# What is the output of C program and why?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p=10,q=20,r;
    if(r = p = 5 || q > 20)
     printf("%d",r);
     else
      printf("No output");

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 1 but how?
Please explain

Comment: because r = p = (5 || q > 20), and it this evaluates to true (1) so it prints r, which is 1

Comment: The title is very poor, even if the question is interesting. It makes it seem more like a trick question rather than a genuine inquiry

Comment: This question would be much improved if you added what you are confused about.  Asking why something is the way it is without context makes your question too broad.  Why do you think it *shouldn't* be 1?  What do you think it *should* be?  What do think is happening?

Comment: To have it come out the way you are thinking, you would need `if ((r = p = 5) || q > 20)`

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Sorry for the confusing title.I just wanted to know how that output is 1

Comment: @zero298 i was confused about how if(r = p = (5 || q > 20) is working?

Comment: @user10050258, for future reference, a much better way to phrase it would have even been _Why is this C function printing an unexpected value?_ and then provided what the expected output was.

Comment: If you're specific we can't know if it because you expect it to print `%d` or `No output` or `it is Friday`. All these have different explanations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). To be more clear:

```
if(r = p = 5 || q > 20)
```

is the same as

```
if(r = p = (5 || q > 20))
```

5 is truthy, so the boolean expression evaluates to 1, which is then assigned to `r`

Answer (score 1):

`r` is being assigned the Boolean results of the 'or' `||` operator. So, `r` is 1 because either `5` or `q > 20` is true.

Answer (score 0):

when you use single '=' operators in conditional statements ,it assigns rhs value to left side identifier .if the rvalue is 0 it gives false else true.so in your case this happened

> p=5 evaluates to p=true
>
> r=p evaluates to r=true
>
> r=true makes condition true

since integer value of true in most compilers is 1 so r contains 1
Also in case of OR if first condition evaluates to true ,then second one is not checked